# Error using geojson_read -- sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt) : unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)

Tags: r, geojson, geojsonio

I'm pretty new with geospatial manipulation in R. I've tried to load in R a map of italy, with this code:

```
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)
map<-geojson_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_provinces.geojson",what="sp")
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt) : unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)
```

Could you please help me? thank you!

Comment: try `library(sf); sf::st_read("https://....etc")`. This will give you an `sf` object, which is the successor to `sp`, and generally considered the better way of using spatial objects in R.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much :)